# Ghost Line Effect with Tables, Email

Tags: email, html-table, line, effect

While developing my email template, I'm experiencing a weird "ghost-line" effect but it only occurs on mobile devices. This ghost line looks like a very thin opaque 1px line.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
<table bgcolor="#cccccc" width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">
            <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="display: block; margin-top: 10px;">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="padding: 5px 20px;">
                        <span style="color: #fff; font-family: Palatino, 'Palatino Linotype', 'Palatino LT STD', 'Book Antiqua', Georgia, serif; font-size: 14px;">
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

Most notably, the effect is really visible when there's two tables stacked ontop of each other and they're the same bgcolor.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in iOS high resolution devices. I have run into it many times and there seems to be no solution. The only alternative I see, is if you wrap everything into a container table and give that one a bg color or use a bg image. It is almost like the 1px is a gap rather and a line because you can see what is behind. It goes away once you zoom in.